# MSI removes required assembly on upgrade install, but replaces it on Repair

Tags: windows-installer, orca, vdproj

I'm experiencing some weirdness related to an MSI installation upgrade, perhaps someone out there can help me:

I have two MSIs, an original and an upgrade:

- MSI version 1.0

  - Contains a .NET assembly, foo.dll, to be installed to the GAC
  - foo.dll is of type "Assembly" (not "Output") within the MSI file system gui.
- MSI version 2.0

  - Also contains foo.dll (same version), plus a bunch additional assemblies.
  - I would like MSI 2.0 to totally replace 1.0, so I set RemovePerviousVersion to False.

Now the two installation scenarios:

1. I run MSI 1.0.  Foo.dll is installed to the GAC properly.  I then run MSI 2.0 and **Foo.dll seems to be removed from the GAC**, but the additional assemblies are there.  I have no idea way.  However, if I go to Add/Remove programs and click "Repair,"  Foo.dll gets put in.
2. MSI 1.0 is never installed and I run MSI 2.0.  Foo.dll (and the additional assemblies) **is** there, as expected.

Any ideas why the foo.dll gets removed during the upgrade??  Thanks in advance!

-Ken

**UPDATE**  After some refreshing/rebuilding, it seems to work now.  However, now it does not remove foo.dll when I uninstall the MSI, even though its property "Permanent" is set to false.  Not as big of a problem, but it would be nice to know what was going on.

Comment: Do you have any upgrades configured (using the `Upgrade` table)?

Comment: Thanks for the response, CSG.  I'm clearly a n00b when it comes to MSIs.  You mentioned the `Upgrade` table, and I've read else that I may need to set REINSTALLMODE property to 'amus' in the `Properties` table.  How do I access/query these tables?  I'm using an MSI deployment project in VS2005.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct the weirdness, I ended up doing the following:

1. Installed Orca.exe, part of the Windows SDK.
2. Added REINSTALLMODE=amus to the Propery table via Orca, post build.

This solved my immediate problem and corrected the install/uninstall issues I was experiencing.  The only problem is that this is a manual process.  Next step, make this a part of an automatic post-build event somehow.